# Insert data in Laravel application from a Wordpress website using mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, laravel

i'm developing an application in Laravel but the thing is: my client already have a wordpress website and wants all registrations made in this website to go automatically to my application. I'm using mysql and the wp website too. 
Can anyone give me a light here? 
Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do you need to get registrations from WP website one time or periodically?

Comment: Siba Al, i need It to be periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give a basic workflow concept.

Do you want that, user will register in wp site, and that time he will be added/registered in the laravel application as well ? If so, then,

Create a user table, User model and userController with a 'store' method in laravel app. This 'store' method will create the user. The table's column names would be better to match the wp site's wp_users table columns name.

Now create an api route in laravel app that will take user data as post parameters. This user data will come from wp site after registration. The api route could be something like this

```
Route::post('store', 'userController@store')->name('users.store');
```

Now in wp site , place this code in 'user_register' hook. This code calls that store api of laravel app and pass the user data of that registered user as user data.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function my_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    //api call
    wp_remote_post( the_api_url, array(
    'user_email' => $user->user_email,
    'user_login' => $user->user_login
    ...
    ...
) )
}
```

Now the wp site is sending the data through the api, your userController's store method have the access of that data. Use that data to store it in laravel's db, the userController's store method will be something like this

```
function store( Request $request) {
  $user = new App\User();
  $user->user_email = $request->user_email,
  $user->user_login = $request->user_login
  ...
  ...
  $user->save()
}
```

That's it.